# how to get part of the url before the question mark

Tags: php

I have a url of the form

`../text?value=`

How can i get the text from the url. $_GET

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use this example:

```
<?php

$uri = Zend_Uri::factory('http://james.bond/some/page/?i=1&a=2');

print_r($uri);
```

This is the result:

```
Zend_Uri_Http Object
(
    [_username:protected] => 
    [_password:protected] => 
    [_host:protected] => james.bond
    [_port:protected] => 
    [_path:protected] => /some/page/
    [_query:protected] => i=1&a=2
    [_fragment:protected] => 
    [_regex:protected] => Array
        (
            [escaped] => %[[:xdigit:]]{2}
            [unreserved] => [A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]]
            [segment] => (?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]:@&=+$,;])*
            [path] => (?:\/(?:(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\]:@&=+$,;])*)?)+
            [uric] => (?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\];\/?:@&=+$,])
        )

    [_scheme:protected] => http
)
```

Doc: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.uri.html

Answer (score 5):

This should help - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.

This would return the text after the last slash.

```
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$url_path_parts = array_filter( explode('/', $url_path) );
print array_pop($url_path_parts);
```

This would return everything after the domain

```
print parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: This isnt going to help, because i don't think they have $url and from the poorly worded question, appears they are trying to get it from the $_GET superglobal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get it from $_GET, thats ONLY stuff after the question mark.  You can however look at $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and parse that out with parse_url or basic string functions.