# Parsing a URL - Php Question

Tags: php, parsing, url

I am using the Following code

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.ewwsdf.org/012Q/rhod-05.php?arg=value#anchor';
$parse = parse_url($url);
$lnk= "http://".$parse['host'].$parse['path'];
echo $lnk;
?>
```

This is giving me the output as

> http://www.ewwsdf.org/012Q/rhod-05.php

How can i modify the code so that i get the output as

> http://www.ewwsdf.org/012Q/

Just need  the Directory name without the file name

( I actually need the link so that i can link up the images which are on the pages, By appending the link behind the image  Eg http://www.ewwsdf.org/012Q/hi.jpg )

Comment: In this question has a brief sample using Zend < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719084/how-to-get-part-of-the-url-before-the-question-mark/4719138#4719138 >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just need the Directory name without the file name

Then use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), eg

```
$lnk= "http://".$parse['host'].dirname($parse['path']);
```

Comment: @Adi To be fair, @nikic gave this same answer first (by 13 seconds)

Answer (score 3):

```
$lnk = "http://".$parse['host'].dirname($parse['path']).'/';
```

[`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) returns the parent directory's path.

Answer (score 3):

use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) instead, it shows relevant info already parsed

Comment: +1. `$parse = pathinfo($url); echo $parse['dirname'];` is exactly what you want.

Comment: @mfonda: No, it isn't he would need to first `parse_url` and then `pathinfo` the `'path'`. It is better in this case to use just `dirname`.

Comment: @nikic: why would he need to first use parse_url()? pathinfo() can take a full URL as an argument

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
$sections = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$folder = $sections[1];
$url = "http://www.ewwsdf.org/".$folder."/";
```